# reversing coordinates in an array variable C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I am not exactly sure how to phrase this question, sorry for the unhelpful title.

I have a large array (5 columns, 50 rows) that I am using to draw out a level environment in ascii text (each entry in the array is a single character and they are all printed out to make an image)
i.e:

```
  char worldarr[5][9] = 
{
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'}, //the length of these entries are actually
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'}, //50 but I shortened them for the post
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
}
```

where the output is:

```
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
```

Now I am trying to set up a coordinate system, where (0,0) is the bottom left hand corner, the goal is to be able to put in a coordinate and have that location replaced with an '@' my original assumption was that I could use this:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
worldarr[y][x] = '@';
```

but this outputs:

```
@XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
```

not:

```
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
@XXXXXXXX
```

how could I make a new system to force (0,0) to be at the bottom, or better yet, the exact center of the array (if possible).

sorry again for the terrible conciseness, I am not sure what I am working with.

Comment: Probably a typo in the question, but `px` != `x`. If it's a typo in the code, well there's your problem.

Comment: To do what I think you're asking for, I'd write a function that translates the outer dimension. Something like `int real_y(int y) { return MAX_Y - y - 1; };` Going a step further, I'd move the array into a class that hid the translation behind an accessor function so the user could never screw up and forget to use the translation function.

Comment: You need to write yourself a little function aXY(x,y) that converts (reverses) the Y-coordinates and swaps x and y.   Or, better yet, define a template XYarray<T> and make it a method.

Comment: why not make a 2D array class that has a member function for changing the origin. Raw C-style arrays are a pain anyway.

Comment: @user4581301, That's Just what I needed, Thank you!

Comment: @OldAmmo Look down at scohe0001's answer. He's doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to completely remap your array, you could instead wrap the array in a class.

Something like:

```
class World {
private:
    static const size_t COLS = 5;
    static const size_t ROWS = 9;
    char worldarr[COLS][ROWS] = 
    {
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'}, //the length of these entries are actually
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'}, //50 but I shortened them for the post
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
    };
public:
    char* operator[](int indx) {
        return worldarr[COLS - (indx + 1)];
    }
};
```

Then you could use it like:

```
World w;
w[0][0] = '@';
```

See a live example here: https://ideone.com/f6xgBb